# Godot 3.1.1 AdMob Android is not detected

Tags: android, admob, godot

OS target (Android/iOS):

```
Android
```

Godot version:

```
3.1.1
```

Issue description:

I am using this repository for the admob and compiled my own templates and tried these compiled ones as well [ https://github.com/Shin-NiL/godot-custom-mobile-template/releases ] and put it in my custom package debug and release paths on android export window and also put the:

```
[android]
modules="org/godotengine/godot/GodotAdMob"
```

but still I get false whenever I try to load the Admob

```
print(Engine.has_singleton("GodotAdMob"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singleton's name is AdMob not GodotAdmob.
Change your line of code to:

```
print(Engine.has_singleton("AdMob"))
```